# ausyscall cannot extract new systemcall

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

Currently, I'm using linux 5.8 on x86.

When I run `ausyscall --dump`, the system call is displayed correctly, but the new systemcall such as `openat2` that is added from linux v5.6 does not appear in the output.

How does `ausyscall` get system calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are generated from per-arch header files, e.g. [`lib/x86_64_table.h`](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/lib/x86_64_table.h). You can see the commit that added `openat2` is [`8f41f04`](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/commit/8f41f042cb779f5f6599ce1f9c4dc96090143a79):

> Update syscall table to the 5.11 kernel
>
> master
> **v3.0.1**
> stevegrubb committed on Jan 18

The information in the headers in turn come from syscall table files from kernel sources. See: [`lib/syscall-update.txt`](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/lib/syscall-update.txt).

> The place where syscall information is gathered is:
>
> [`arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl)
> [`arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/unistd.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/unistd.h)
> [`arch/powerpc/include/uapi/asm/unistd.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/powerpc/include/uapi/asm/unistd.h)
> [`arch/s390/kernel/syscalls/syscall.tbl`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/s390/kernel/syscalls/syscall.tbl)
> [`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl)
> [`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl)
> [`include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h)  (aarch64)

Comment: Thank you very much!
I have a question.
If ausyscall's `lib/x86_64_table.h` dose not have the new system call such as `openat2`, I cannot get the system call even if the kernel supports the system call, right?  
If so, I think that ausyscall dose not need `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` anymore because the ausyscall does not depend on the kernel version.  
Cloud you tell me about this?

Comment: `ausyscall` is only for interpreting audit messages and not used for the actual syscall interface. So it is not tied to the specific kernel version running. I'm sure occasional edits (possibly manual), like the commit linked above, are probably good enough for their purpose. It has no bearing on the syscalls you can call.

Comment: The version of the `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` that was used for building the kernel you are running is the authoritative source for which syscall numbers your kernel knows about. If you use that number and call `syscall`, it would work.

Comment: Thank you for the kind reply! I understand clearly. I misunderstood ausyscall. `ausyscall` just extract system call using `lib/x86_64_table.h` that is not depend on kernel version.  Is my understanding correct?